# Dynamic number of parallel steps in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a declarative pipeline which does a number (configurable via parameter) jobs in parallel, but I'm having trouble with the parallel part.

Basically, for some reason the below pipeline generates the error

```
 Nothing to execute within stage "Testing" @ line .., column ..
```

and I cannot figure out why, or how to solve it.

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field def mayFinish = false

def getJob() {
    return {
        lock("finiteResource") {
            waitUntil {
                script {
                    mayFinish
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getFinalJob() {
    return {
        waitUntil {
            script {
                try {
                    echo "Start Job"
                    sleep 3 // Replace with something that might fail.
                    echo "Finished running"
                    mayFinish = true
                    true
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    echo e.toString()
                    echo "Failed :("
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getJobs(def NUM_JOBS) {
    def jobs = [:]
    for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_JOBS as Integer); i++) {
        jobs["job{i}"] = getJob()
    }
    jobs["finalJob"] = getFinalJob()
    return jobs
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'5'))
    }
    parameters {
        string(
            name: "NUM_JOBS",
            description: "Set how many jobs to run in parallel"
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                echo "Setting it up..."
            }
        }
        stage('Testing') {
            steps {
                parallel getJobs(params.NUM_JOBS)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen plenty of examples doing this in the old pipeline, but not declarative.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you stripping the line numbers away? Isn't that useful information? Have you tried a minimal example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, it doesn't seem possible to dynamically provide the `parallel` branches when using a Declarative Pipeline.

Even if you have a `stage` prior where, in a `script` block, you call `getJobs()` and add it to the binding, the same error message is thrown.

In this case you'd have to fall back to using a Scripted Pipeline.

Comment: While it wasn't what I wanted to hear - it's at least something I can work with. Thanks.

Comment: Is this still impossible? What about a solution where a fixed (maximum supported) number of parallel jobs are started and only the first X jobs continue. Where X is provided via parameter. Would that work?